# WordPress nav walker split into three columns

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I want to split my menu into three columns, curretly it's spliting into two columns. I am using nav walker class. I am having 12 links in my menu, so the calculation part is dividing by 2. I tried dividing by 3 but doesn't work.

Help me out guys

Spliting part is coming from this code

```
if( !isset( $this->break_point ) )
$this->break_point = ceil( $this->current_menu->count / 2 ) + 1;
```

Here is the code that I have so far

```
class footer_nav_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

var $current_menu = null;
var $break_point  = null;

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {

    global $wp_query;

    if( !isset( $this->current_menu ) )
        $this->current_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $args->menu );

    if( !isset( $this->break_point ) )
        $this->break_point = ceil( $this->current_menu->count / 2 ) + 1;

    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    if( $this->break_point == $item->menu_order )
        $output .= $indent . '</li></ul><ul class="footerBreak"><li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';
    else
        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}


function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
}
}
```

Comment: instead of doing that much traverse through menu object using a counter and check it's equal to count/3 or not if yes then add next ul and make count 0 again.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Can you help me with the code?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Getting very long output, do I need to include in my question?